# C - Accessing struct within a struct

Tags: c, struct

I was doing a project in C.And I am quite new to C. In the project, I have a struct like this :

```
struct room_t{
   char* name;
   struct room_t* north;
   struct room_t* east;
   struct room_t* south;
   struct room_t* west;
}
```

declared as : `struct room_t room[3]`

If I want to access the name in north, I do this :`room[0].north[0]->name`

Am I right ?  or should it be `room[0].north[0].name`

Comment: the irst one is correct, since the fields (or properties) are pointers. well, it never hurt to give a shot.

Comment: It's a matter of type, just try it, one will compile and one will not. Though it would be poor form, assuming memory is correctly allocated, the "imo most readable" way would be `room[0].north->name`

Comment: There are no `struct`s in your `struct`! What is unclear about dereferencing a pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first guess is almost correct, but it should be `room[0].north->name` since you didn't declare an array for the variable `north`.

In general, you should give it a try and then see what outputs the compiler and your progam to learn as much as possible by yourself. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It should be 
room[0].north->name, if you allocate single element in north
But if you allocate an array(more than one element) into north, you should access as room[0].north[n].name where n=0 to (number of elements allocated) - 1